# Importing CSV from URL and displaying rows on Python by using Requests

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

```
import csv
import requests
webpage = requests.get('http://www.pjm.com/pub/account/lmpda/20160427-da.csv')
reader=csv.reader(webpage)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Hi, I'm new to Python and I'm trying to open a CSV file from a URL & then display the rows so I can take the data that I need from it. However, the I get an error saying :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       for row in reader: Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [Response Content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import csv, requests
webpage=requests.get('http://www.pjm.com/pub/account/lmpda/20160427-da.csv')
reader = csv.reader(webpage.content.splitlines())
for row in reader:
  print(row)
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still get the same error message ;
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: Did you run the same code ? This code works for me. The 3rd line must be exactly like this : reader = csv.reader(webpage.content.splitlines())

Answer (score 0):

Use *.text* as you are getting *bytes* returned in python3:

```
webpage = requests.get('http://www.pjm.com/pub/account/lmpda/20160427-da.csv')
reader = csv.reader([webpage.text])
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

That gives `_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field` so split the lines after decoding, also `stream=True` will allow you to get the data in chunks not all at once so you can filter by row and write:

```
import csv
import requests


webpage = requests.get('http://www.pjm.com/pub/account/lmpda/20160427-da.csv', stream=1)

for line in webpage:
     print(list(csv.reader((line.decode("utf-8")).splitlines()))[0])
```

Which gives you:

```
['Day Ahead Hourly LMP Values for 20160427', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['00', '600', '700', '800', '900', '1000', '1100', '1200', '1300', '1400', '1500', '1600', '1700', '1800', '1900', '2000', '2100', '2200', '2300', '2400', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['1', '25.13', '25.03', '28.66', '25.94', '21.74', '19.47', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['600', '600', '600', '700', '700', '700', '800', '800', '800', '900', '900', '900', '1000', '1000', '1000', '1100', '1100', '1100', '1200', '1200', '1200', '1300', '1300', '1300', '1400', '1400', '1400', '1500', '']
['1500', '1500', '1600', '1600', '1600', '1700', '1700', '1700', '1800', '1800', '1800', '1900', '1900', '1900']
['', '2000', '2000', '2000', '2100', '2100', '2100', '2200', '2200', '2200', '2300', '2300', '2300', '2400', '2400', '2400', '']
['lLMP', 'CongestionPrice', 'MarginalLossPrice', 'TotalLMP', 'CongestionPrice', 'MarginalLossPrice', 'TotalLMP', 'CongestionPrice', 'MarginalLossPrice', 'Tot']
['alLMP', 'CongestionPrice', 'MarginalLossPrice', 'TotalLMP', 'CongestionPrice', 'MarginalLossPrice', 'TotalLMP', 'CongestionPrice', 'MarginalLossPrice', 'To']
['talLMP', 'CongestionPrice', 'MarginalLossPrice', 'TotalLMP', 'CongestionPrice', 'MarginalLossPrice', 'TotalLMP', 'CongestionPrice', 'MarginalLossPrice', 'T']
.......................................
```

Comment: Thx but now I'm getting a new error which is 
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: @mostafa14, I added a couple of alternatives

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the answer by [Padriac Cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham) uses `iter_lines()` from `Requests` and decodes each line using a list comprehension

```
import csv
import requests

webpage = requests.get('http://www.pjm.com/pub/account/lmpda/20160427-da.csv', stream = True)
webpage_decoded = [line.decode('utf-8') for line in webpage.iter_lines()]
reader = csv.reader(webpage_decoded)
```

or even simpler, you can have `iter_lines()` do the decoding

```
webpage_decoded = webpage.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True)
```